# Arduino IDE Using flash helper in const Struct

Tags: c, struct, initialization, arduino-uno

I have written an Arduino code last week using my linux laptop. There everything is working properly. Now I'm trying to get the same code running using the IDE on Windows. There the compiler is complaining about the initialization of a const struct containing a const pointer to a string in flash memory. Using the F() marco out of wString in the initialization is not working on Windows. Is there any workaround?

```
typedef struct
{
    const __FlashStringHelper* desc;
    int a;    
} SensorStringInformation;

void setup()
{
       const SensorStringInformation res
       {
          F("Depth: "),
          2
       };
}

void loop()
{

}
```

Many thanks

Comment: That's probably because the `F` macro and the `__FlashStringHelper` type are compiler-dependent, and extensions of the language implemented only by the Arduino compiler.

Comment: Does "the IDE on Windows" mean the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry for being inaccurate. Arduino IDE on linux and windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem. If I modify my code like this it's working properly in both cases:

```
typedef struct
{
    const __FlashStringHelper* desc;
    int a;    
} SensorStringInformation;

void setup()
{
       const SensorStringInformation res = 
       {
          F("Depth: "),
          2
       };
}

void loop()
{

}
```